# Changing State of a Component by Input from children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I've got three forms - sign in, forgot password and sign up. Initial render is for a sign in component which has buttons for forget password or sign up. On click the buttons render their each respective component.

Where I am right now is that I have state assigned to each child component I want rendered and buttons changing the state in the parent component . I want to move these buttons to the child components so that I can change the state from there

Below is the sign in page and two of the three components I've mentioned.

```
export default function SigninPage() {
  const [comp, setView] = useState('signin')
  function toggleSignin(comp){
    setView('signin')
  }
  function toggleReset(comp){
    setView('reset')
  }
  function toggleSignup(comp){
    setView('signup')
  }
  return (
    <LoginStyles>
      {comp ==='signin' &&(
        <div>
          <SignIn />
        </div>
        )
      }
      {comp ==='reset' &&(
        <div><RequestReset/></div>
        )
      }
      {comp ==='signup' &&(
        <div><SignUp/></div>
        )
      }
      <button onClick={toggleSignin}>Sign In</button>
      <button onClick={toggleReset}>Forgot Password</button>
      <button onClick={toggleSignup}>Sign Up</button>

    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export default function SignIn() {
  return (
    <Form>
      <h2>Sign Into Your Account</h2>
      <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
      {/* onClick sets state to 'signup'*/}
      <a>Create a New Account</a>
      <a>Forgot Password</a>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

```
export default function RequestReset() {
  return (
    <Form    >
      {/* onClick sets state to 'signin'*/}
      <a href='/signin'>**Go back**</a>
      <h2>Request a Password Reset</h2>
      <fieldset>
        <label htmlFor='email'>
          Email
        </label>
        <button type='submit'>Request Reset</button>
      </fieldset>
    </Form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I believe you should implement this behavior with routing, that approach you are using is definitely messy and hard to follow.
That said, I think the follow will do the trick:

```
<LoginStyles>
  {items.map(({ id, component, isVisible }) => (
     const Component = component;
     <div key={id} hidden={!isVisible}>
       <Component onClickComponent={() => handleClick(id)}
     </div>
   ))}
</LoginStyles>
```

Of course you need to call onClickComponent later on in the childs, but you will have scope and keep the id.

Comment: Yea, routing these forms would get me around this problem, but I want to control them by their state. I did try with your suggestion but could not get it to work, unfortunately.

Comment: I've changed my approach (and edited the question). I'm getting the result I want but still need not sure how to move the button functions to the child components.

Comment: Nevermind, I just moved the buttons into the divs with the child components and it works

Comment: Been off for a few days, I just made this codesandox with I belive is what u were looking for. Didnt really know where to put the button to display the reset component but it easy to follow so you will figure out. https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-chatelet-fu4s8